# Postgres container not recognizing POSTGRES_USER_FILE environment variable

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm

For whatever reason I can't get postgres to recognize the POSTGRES_USER_FILE environment variable.

With the following secret:

```
echo "pass" | docker secret create psql_pass -
```

When I create the following service i can log in (using adminer) using the account "pass":"pass"

```
Docker service create --name psql --secret psql_pass -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/psql_pass -e POSTGRES_USER=pass postgres
```

But when I create THIS service, I CANNOT log in using the same account "pass":"pass"

```
Docker service create --name psql --secret psql_pass -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/psql_pass -e POSTGRES_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/psql_pass postgres
```

(yes, it should be user:pass, but I wanted to illustrate that its the exact same secret being used)

I have verified that the secret is being set correctly in the container (cat /run/secrets/psql_pass)

Am I missing something here? Why isn't POSTGRES_USER_FILE being recognized?

Comment: Is POSTGRES_USER_FILE documented someplace?

Comment: @jjanes It is documented in the Docker Secrets section of the docker hub page: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the following docker compose to define the postgres database service

```
    postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    container_name: db-mlflow-tracking
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres-u
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/postgres-p
    user: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - store-pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
    secrets:
      - postgres-u
      - postgres-p
  secrets:
    postgres-u:
      file: postgres-u.txt 
    postgres-p:
      file: postgres-p.txt
```

where files postgres-u.txt and postgres-p.txt resides on the path as docker-compose.yaml file